# Using ExternalObjects for python iterators

Tags: python, external-calls, external-language-cell

[Iterators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) are a common pattern in python.  A trivial example is:

```python
example = iter(("apple", "banana", "cherry"))
next(example)
```

(yes, of course, one does not need to treat this specific case as an iterator, it is just a minimal example)

**How does one effectively work with iterators using the [ExternalEvaluate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) / [ExternalFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalFunction.html) in Mathematica?**

Some strategies that do **not** work:

## Strategy 1: ExternalObject

The tuple iterator gets returned as an [ExternalObject](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalObject.html), but then there is a type conversion error when sending it back to python to apply the `next()` function to it:

```mathematica
(* create a python session *)
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];

(* define the iterator, returning a ExternalObject *)
ex = ExternalEvaluate[session, "iter((\"apple\", \"banana\", \"cherry\"))"] 

(* define the next function *)
next = ExternalFunction[session, "next"];

(* but...applying the next function returns an error *)
next[ex] 
(* Error Message: WLFunction' object is not an iterator *)
```

## Strategy 2: PythonObject

The [PythonObject resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PythonObject/) seems like it should help.  Iterators define a `__next()__` method that we should be able to call, but this does not seem to work:

```mathematica
(* define the PythonObject *)
ex2 = ResourceFunction["PythonObject"]["iter((\"apple\", \"banana\", \"cherry\"))"]

(* ex2["__next__"[]] *)
(* Failure: Message: name __next__ is not defined *)

(* ex2["next"[]] *)
(* Failure: Message: tuple_iterator has no attribute `next` *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you need:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[session, "x = iter((\"apple\", \"banana\", \"cherry\"))"] ;
ExternalValue[session, "next(x)"]
ExternalValue[session, "next(x)"]
ExternalValue[session, "next(x)"]
DeleteObject[session] ;
(* apple *)
(* banana *)
(* cherry *)
```

Comment: It's certainly one workaround (and I suppose that the global state of `x` is confined to `session`